# Can't explain Awk behaviour

Tags: bash, awk

I'm new in bash scripting. In my script I need to remove lines not beginning with the 'a' character from a text file, writing these lines in temp.txt file. I'm using this syntax of awk to do the job.

```
read value
awk '($1 != "$value" ) ' file1.txt > temp.txt
```

When I run the script it says at the beginning all the lines which don't begin with the value, and then the lines beginning with the value.
Can someone explain to me why this happens and eventually suggest me a correction?

Comment: `awk -v val="$value" '$1 != val' file1.txt > temp.txt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you can use `grep`:

```
grep -v '^a' file1 > file2
```

`^` matches the beginning of the line. `^a` matches an `a` at the beginning of the line. `-v` negates the match meaning grep will output all lines which does not start with an `a`.

If you want to pass a variable to that command, you'll need to use double quotes instead of single quotes:

```
grep -v "^$value" file1 > file2
```

But be aware of the fact that `$value` will get interpreted as a regular expression. Meaning if `value=.` for example, it would match any character, not just the literal `.`.

To circumvent that, awk comes in mind again and that's my final suggestion:

```
awk -v value="$value" 'substr($0,0,length(value)) != value' file1 > file2
```

Comment: Why avoid the direct `==` on `$1` like the OP tried? And given the caveats with the variable-as-regex why start by recommending `grep`?

Comment: @EtanReisner Op says: Lines not beginning with a certain character. But yes, I could have used `-F''` and then check `$1` that's true. Good point. However, since the `read` command in the question does not limit the length, imo the final `awk` command I've suggested is the most flexible solution. About grep, if regex characters are not a problem or even desired, grep is the best solution. That's why I've added that and started with that.

Answer (score 1):

Variables aren't expanded in single quotes. What your script does is it excludes all lines starting with the string `$value` literally followed by whitespace.

Comment: The whitespace is outside of the quotes so isn't part of the match.

Comment: @EtanReisner: But `$value` is followed by whitespace, otherwise the following character would be part of $1, right?

Comment: I resolved using the grep command...but I really want to get a solution even with awk

Comment: Yeah, the OP wasn't entirely clear on whether the value was the entire first field or not and that complicates getting the "right" solution.